# JNDI lookup failed for Resource

Tags: java, websphere, jndi, ejb-3.1, ibm-rad

I am running EJB application with RAD+Webshere-8.5.1. I have to add send email functionality in my EJB, for that I configured dummy mail session in IBM console application as follow
[image]

And I am trying to access in my Stateless Ejb as

@Resource(name="mail/sandMailSession")
private Session sandMailSession;

But its failing, as NameNotFoundException.

Do we required other setting to bind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'mail/sandMailSession' is the name defined in the global namespace. You should bind mail session to the local component namespace by using `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` file inside `META-INF` directory:

```
<ejb-jar-bnd xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-ejb-jar-bnd_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
  <session name="NAME_OF_EJB">
    <resource-ref name="mail/sandMailSession" binding-name="mail/sandMailSession"/>
  </session>
</ejb-jar-bnd>
```

Please note that `name` and `binding-name` are separate attributes and can have different values, although in your case they are the same. `binding-name` is the name of a resource in the global namespace.